# What is the max amount of photons per second of the rods and cones in our eyes?

Tags: human-biology

The title says it all. I just cannot find any information about this - I have tried for so long now. Therefore, I figured that I could reach out to some clever guys in this forum for help instead:)

Also, if it is possible, I would love a link to read more about it.

Comment: what did you find? It's much better if you show the information that you've found so far, it may help others to know how far you've got and where you're stuck.

Comment: Nothing, quite simple :(